# Send email with attachment with phonegap

Tags: email, cordova

What is the best way to send an email with attachment with phonegap? It should work on WP7,android and IOS.
The [Email Composer](https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/EmailComposer) plugin unfortunately only works on Android and IOS and mailto doesn't support attachments.